# How to add a column fill with values to the table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have table which has a column age. I categorized this age column like this way

```
select 
CASE WHEN age>60 THEN 'old'
WHEN age between 30 and 60 THEN 'middled age'
WHEN age between 20 and 30 THEN 'young'
WHEN age between 13 and 20 THEN 'teen'
else 'kid'
end as age_category
from customer
```

Now i want this `age_category` to add to `customer` table. So I created an empty column

```
ALTER table customer add column age_category varchar;
```

The next I want to fill it up with values, so i tried to add the output of first statement using insert command like the following way

```
INSERT INTO customer (age_category) values
(SELECT
CASE WHEN age>60 THEN 'old'
WHEN age between 30 and 60 THEN 'middled age'
WHEN age between 20 and 30 THEN 'young'
WHEN age between 13 and 20 THEN 'teen'
ELSE'kid'
END as age_category
FROM customer)
```

but it did not worked

Comment: Alternate to an `UPDATE`, is a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) where the `case` statement is the expression.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want an *update* here, not an insert:

```sql
UPDATE customer
SET age_category = CASE WHEN age >= 60 THEN 'old'
                        WHEN age >= 30 THEN 'middle aged'
                        WHEN age >= 20 THEN 'young'
                        WHEN age >= 13 THEN 'teen'
                        ELSE 'kid' END;
```

However, given that `age_category` is derived data, you might want to consider *not* storing this as a column.  The reason is that anytime the `age` data should change (via update/insert) you would have to regenerate the `age_category` values.  Another option, if you're using MySQL 8+, might be to use a generated column.

Answer (score 1):

Add generated column.

```sql
ALTER TABLE customer 
ADD COLUMN age_category VARCHAR(255) 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CASE WHEN age > 60 THEN 'old'
                               WHEN age > 29 THEN 'middle aged'
                               WHEN age > 19 THEN 'young'
                               WHEN age > 12 THEN 'teen'
                               ELSE 'kid' 
                               END );
```

If `age` column value changes then the value of this generated column changes automatically.